# Axios Error 401 (Unauthorized) Error when trying to fetch api

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, axios, postman

> 

- Error: Request failed with status code 401
- at createError (createError.js:16)
  -at settle (settle.js:17)
- at XMLHttpRequest.handleLoad (xhr.js:62)

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import axios from 'axios';
class QuestionAPI extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      items: [],
      MYTOKEN: "cqondiodwoidndndjjajajejh.ndoqndnodnqodoqdiapoe89wnwjwmalmqql2mkKKMkmwk"
    };
  }
  componentDidMount = (MYTOKEN) => {
    axios.get(`http://192.168.0.10:9000/getquestions`,{
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        "token": 'Bearer' + MYTOKEN
      },
    })
      .then(res => {
        console.log("res" + res)
      })
      .catch(e => console.log(e))
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
      </div>
    );
  };
}
export default QuestionAPI;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few issues with your code.

- The `componentDidMount` method doesn't receive any arguments. So, you have to get the token from [`localStorage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) (assuming you're storing the token in it). And you should remove the hardcoded token from the component state.
- The token should be sent in the `Authorization` header (your code sends it in `token` and that's why the API sends a `401 Unauthorized` response). And there should be a space next to `Bearer`.

```js
Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`
```

- You shouldn't hardcode the API URL. Use environment variables. If you're using [Create React App](https://create-react-app.dev/), you can [add environment variables prefixed with `REACT_APP_` to `.env`](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-custom-environment-variables/#adding-development-environment-variables-in-env) or you can use [dotenv-webpack](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv-webpack) if you have a custom Webpack setup.

```js
componentDidMount = () => {
  const token = localStorage.getItem('token') // Replace token with the right key
  if (!token) {
    // handle no token case
    return
  }

  axios.get(`${process.env.API_BASE_URL}/getquestions`, {
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      Accept: 'application/json',
      Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
    },
  })
}
```